# CRUD Methods for UWP Template

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have been looking at using the UWP Template for VS 2017 and built a prototype app with it.  It works great for displaying existing data, but for save/update operations are not defined at all for the pages created by the template.  Does anyone know of any samples that include the other CRUD operations?  For those of us who are new to UWP, this can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

There are some blogposts and GitHub repositories with CRUD-based samples. You can check out for example [this repository](https://github.com/johnshew/Minimal-UWP-MVVM-CRUD), [this blog post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/crud-operations-in-uwa-using-web-api/) with ASP.NET WebAPI as backend or [this article on building a minimal app](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnshews_blog/2015/09/09/a-minimal-mvvm-uwp-app/) with CRUD operations.

Overall, it is easy to find samples if you search for a specific way the data are stored - for example SQLite, file-based, Web API, etc.